# Oracle Client Universal Installer crashes

Tags: oracle12c, oracleclient

on my Windows Server 2012 R2 machine I've got installed multiple Oracle 12c client components such as Oracle Net, JDBC, OCI etc etc.

Now I want to add a component ("Oracle Services for MTS").

I launch the universal installer as Administrator, select the oracle home of my existing client installation, select the MTS component.

But during the installation after reaching 54% and the task "Registry Key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTARE/ORACLE/KEY_OraClient12Home1_32Bit", I get an error message "Failed to Grant Privileges on specified Oracle home type"
I can do nothing else than aborting the installation.

It is suspicious that this registry is not existing. As the client is a 32 bit client the correct key is
".../**WOW6432Node**/ORACLE/KEY_OraClient12Home1_32Bit"...

- The administrator user used to do the installation has all rights in the oracle home directory, as well as all other users do.
- The oracle home user is called "OracleHomeUser"

Are you guys having any idea what is going wrong here ??

Comment: If its a 32 bit installer then the OS should redirect registry access to wow automatically so that may be a false lead.  If that 32 bit key exists you could try changing its permissions to everyone for the duration.  process-monitor would highlight any issues relating to system permissions.

Comment: I was able to press "Continue" after the error was appearing. But now I reach the step where I need to create the Oracle MTS Service. When I do `oramtsctl.exe -new` I get the error "unsupported oracle home type". What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this issue yesterday when attempting to add OraMTS to an existing 12.1 64 bit database home on 2008 R2.

The registry key for your Oracle Home should exist at either of the following locations:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_*{Oracle_Home_Name}`, or
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_*{Oracle_Home_Name}`, where `{Oracle_Home_Name}` is your Oracle Home Name (e.g., OraDB12Home1, or OraClient12Home1_32bit, etc.).

Within this key there are many values, one of which is a REG_SZ (string) value called ORACLE_HOME_TYPE. It needs to have a value populated (e.g., set to "1" for a database home, "2" for a client home, etc.).

In my case, ORACLE_HOME_TYPE was blank, which was causing the error to appear during installation of OraMTS. Since I was installing into a database home, I set the value to "1" and the installation completed successfully.

In your case, if the registry key is altogether missing, or if the key is present but ORACLE_HOME_TYPE has no set value, then you will get these errors when adding components.

Were you able to find the key at one of the above locations in the registry? If so, review the value of ORACLE_HOME_TYPE and set to "2" if you are adding these components to a client installation.

Comment: This solution applies to later version(s) also. I had to manually change the ORACLE_HOME_TYPE for 19c MTS installation. Thanks @Jonathan B